# Tricky Gaussian

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone do

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{a+bx^{2}}e^{-\beta\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}dydx
$$

Perhaps this post could help: [Integrating a product of exponentials and error functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78615/integrating-a-product-of-exponentials-and-error-functions?rq=1)

Comment: sorry to repost this, but I consider it a different question to a previous post. The down vote is unnecessary.

Comment: have you made any progress? E.g., is it possible to pull the $e^{-\beta x^2}$ into the outer integral?

Comment: yes, essentially it becomes an exponential times a error function with the inner upper limit for an argument

Comment: This is indeed

$$\int^\infty_0e^{-\beta x^2}dx\int^{a+bx^2}_0e^{-\beta y^2}dy=\frac{1}{2}\beta^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\int^{a+bx^2}_0e^{-y^2 \beta }dy$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. Hope this helps.

Comment: But this is wrong, since the second part is x-dependent.

Comment: Have you tried polar co-ordinates?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I don't think that's right. The limit of integration on the right integral involves $x$ so you have to keep the $dx$ after the $dy$, i.e. the integrals can't be factored in this way.

Comment: @TooTone I understand. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: you're going to need to look at the reference in the OP

Comment: can someone expand on converting this to polar coordinates?

Comment: I think polars makes the limits too complex, leading to an even trickier Gaussian.